# When do UK creditors pursue a debt after the debtor has died?

Tags: united-kingdom, debt, death

[According to StepChange](https://www.stepchange.org/debt-info/bereavement-and-debt.aspx), creditors don't normally pursue a debt of someone who died if there isn't a large estate:

> Most unsecured creditors will normally write off a debt (like a personal loan or credit card) if there's little or no money left when a person dies. They’ll normally only pursue the debt if there’s a large estate.

What would be considered a large estate here? I realise this will depend on the creditor and the size of the debt, but are there any rules of thumb or statistics about this?

If a creditor wanted to go after someone's clothes or their toaster, is there anything legally preventing them from doing that?

Comment: As far as I know if you want to make sure you don´t inherit the debt, you have to reject the entire legacy. That would normally not mean that you can´t dissolve the household, but any monetary values would got to the creditors and they´d have to write off the rest. If you choose to inherit, you´d inherit the debt too. This is for Germany though, don´t know for the UK.

Comment: A will might say "I leave £1,000 to my best frind Daniel to have a pint on me every day as long as the money lasts". In that case, the debt will be paid first; you don't have to refuse the inheritance but you will just not get any money.